# Rotating through file and assign first column to different variables based on infos in following columns

Tags: bash, shell

Following input-file:

```
 AEGUEUS SA 
 APOLLO 
 ARES 
 ARTEMIS MO TU WE TH FR 
 ATHENA MO TU WE TH FR 
 HADES MO TU WE TH FR 
 AGAFYA MO TU WE TH FR 
 HERMES MO TU WE TH FR 
 HESTIA MO TU WE TH FR 
 POSEIDON MO TU WE TH FR 
 ATLAS MO TU WE TH FR 
 AURA MO TU WE TH FR 
 EOS MO TU WE TH FR 
 UBON MO TU WE TH FR 
 PERSES MO TU WE TH FR 
 PALLAS MO TU WE TH FR 
 STYX 
 UDOM SA 
 LETO MO TU WE TH FR 
 SELENE MO TU WE TH FR 
 ASTERIA MO WE FR SU
 OCEANUS MO TU WE TH FR 
 CRONUS TU SU
 ACHILLES TU SU
```

I have a variable for each weekday, the first column should be added to the corresponding variable if the following columns match one of the weekdays.

For example, AEGUS should be added to SA. APOLLO and ARES have no weekdays, so they are not added to anything. ARTEMIS should be added to MO TU WE TH FR, same for ATHENA, HADES and so on.....

So what i thought about was something like a "while read line" loop into an array for each line, followed by a case-match for every column and filling the variables based on it. But i have no clue how to do this properly. I already got stuck at the while loop, this is what i came up with, but i think it's pretty much wrong.

```
while IFS=" " read -r line
do
    array=($line)
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
        case $i in
            MO)
            MO=()
            MO+=("${array[1]}")
            ;;
            TU)
            TU=()
            TU+=("${array[1]}")
            ;;
            WE)
            WE=()
            WE+=("${array[1]}")
            ;;
            TH)
            TH=()
            TH+=("${array[1]}")
            ;;
            FR)
            FR=()
            FR+=("${array[1]}")
            ;;
            SA)
            SA=()
            SA+=("${array[1]}")
            ;;
            SO)
            SO=()
            SO+=("${array[1]}")
            ;;
        esac
done < days.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weekdays=(MO TU WE TH FR SA SU)
wdpat=$(IFS=\|; echo "${weekdays[*]}")

while read name days || [[ -n $name ]]; do
    for day in $days; do
        if [[ $day = @($wdpat) ]]; then
            # safe because day contains MO .. SU
            eval "$day"'+=( "$name" )'
        fi
    done
done

for day in "${weekdays[@]}"; do
    ref="$day"'[@]'
    echo "$day: ${!ref}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off approaching the problem searching one day at a time and so something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for day in "MO" "TU" "WE" "TH" "FR" "SA" "SU"
do
        mapfile $day < <(grep "$day" days | awk '{ printf $1"\n" }')
done
```

Here we take each day at a time and use the day to search file (days) for that day. The output is then parsed through awk as we are only concerned with the first column and new lines are added to the names so that we can then pipe the output through map file to create the array associated with that given day.